# Не могу понять как работает замыкание функции

Tags: javascript

Я только учусь и не понимаю, почему выводит undefined. По заданию функция должна принимать другую функцию и возвращать результат вызова этой функции

```js
function returnFnResult(fn) {
  function returnFn(fn) {
    return fn;
  }

  return returnFn();
}

const resultFn = returnFnResult(2);

console.log(resultFn);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что в теле функции `returnFnResult` Вы вызываете подфункцию `returnFn()` БЕЗ аргументов, хотя данная функция была объявлена с ОДНИМ аргументом — из-за этого JS не может найти указанную Вами функцию и выводит `undefined`. Добавьте аргумент `fn` к вызову `returnFn`, и тогда должно будет вывестись значение этого аргумента (здесь — 2):

```js
function returnFnResult(fn) {
  function returnFn(fn) {
    return fn;
  }

  return returnFn(fn);
}

const resultFn = returnFnResult(2);

console.log(resultFn);
```

UPD: по замечаниям Igor привожу другую версию кода:

```js
function returnFnResult() {
  let num = 2;
  function returnFn() {
    return num;
  }
  return returnFn;
}

const f = returnFnResult();

console.log(f());
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь, я подозревал, что дело в аргументе, но видимо неправильно писал синтаксис) Подскажите, а почему нельзя в значение аргумента положить слово? Например, "пельмени"?

Comment: @DanielMaslov пожалуйста. Насчёт пельменей: можно в значение аргумента подставить любое слово, нужно представить его как `"пельмени"` с двойными кавычками по бокам.

`returnFnResult("пельмени") // как пример`

P.S. Если ответ Вам помог, не забывайте отмечать его как верный, нажав на галочку слева от текста

Comment: Ааа, принял, благодарю. К сожалению, сайт не даёт сделать это сразу, жду таймер и обязательно поставлю)

Comment: чтобы явно было замыкание лучше убрать параметр `returnFn` вообще

Comment: @DanielMaslov окей, просто пишу к сведению, дабы не было много якобы "заброшенных вопросов", в которых ответ помог автору, но тот не отметил его официально :)

Comment: @Grundy буду знать. Спасибо вам за помощь в моих начинаниях)

Comment: @4500zenja Какой в этом смысл, и при чем здесь замыкание?

Comment: @Igor изначально я исправил версию кода от DanielMaslov, но про замыкание забыл, виноват. Сейчас добавил вторую версию уже с ним